# What's the name of these 2 caching techniques?

Tags: http, caching, cache-control

I'm currently studying how to cache the HTML pages generated by a server for faster loading for the clients (both in PHP and Python web frameworks).

Let's say the server takes 200ms to generate `http://example.com/?id=<numberhere>`.

What is the name of these two slightly different techniques:

- client-side caching: if user A has visited `http://example.com/?id=1` once, then if **user A** visits the same page a second time, it will be faster.
  If **user B** visits it later, the first visit will be slow again.
- server-side caching: if user A has visited `http://localhost/?id=1` once, then if user B visits this page later (even if it's the first time for user B!), it will be faster too.
  In other words: if 200 ms is spent to generate `http://localhost/?id=1` for one user, it will be cached for *all future users* requesting the same page.

?

I have read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control but I'm not sure which one of these techniques this applies to.

Comment: Clientside / Serverside caching are the names? Serverside caching works only for non-customizes pages - say Rightmanangement & User A != User B rights then the caching wont work - but f.e. if the server contacts other services it needs to populate the site those accesses could be cached and the created page cached for some time until a refresh should be triggered?

Comment: @PatrickArtner When we say [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) and [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), it is specific to *one* client, i.e. it allows to reuse a previous response. Is that right?